# Cite all publications with some author from bibtex in org mode

Tags: org-mode

I would like to `nocite` all of my papers in an org document to make a publication list.  Because of how I format my reference keys in the `.bib` file, this would be quite easy with pattern matching, but I expect that this is not supported by the `cite` syntax.

Is this easy to do without `nocite`ing each paper?  Ideally the list will self-update as I add references (so all I need to do is export when I want a fresh copy).

I've looked at the [citation handling](https://orgmode.org/manual/Citation-handling.html) and [citations](https://orgmode.org/manual/Citations.html) pages in the org manual, to no avail (I know the cite syntax is pretty newly incorporated, and documentation is still sparse).  I expect there is a programmatic solution, but my `elisp` is a bit rusty.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You could create a bib file with all your publications, require
the `oc-biblatex` library, and then export the following to latex (`C-c C-e l l`):

```
#+title: Publications
#+cite_export: biblatex
#+bibliography: file.bib

[cite/n:@*]

#+print_bibliography:

# Local Variables:
# org-cite-global-bibliography: nil
# End:
```

You should be able to get similar results when exporting to HTML
etc., at least in theory, using the `#+cite_export: cls`
processor (see `org-cite-export-processors`), but for some reason
it fails with the `cite/n` syntax.