# How to export bibliographies with Org-Mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Org-Mode can now handle citations through `#+bibliography: biblio.bib` and `org-cite-insert`. For example, `[cite:@ref1; @ref2]` in an org file, will show `@ref1` and `@ref2` short content contained in `biblio.bib`, in the exported HTML file.

How can I make a bibliography headline showing `@ref1` and `@ref2` extended content, or the whole content of `biblio.bib` in the exported HTML?

Answer (score 5):

- Making a bibliography showing `@ref1` and `@ref2`:

```
#+bibliography: biblio.bib
* Content
  Example[cite:@ref1; @ref2]
* Bibliography
#+print_bibliography:
```

- Making a bibliography showing the whole content of biblio.bib:

```
#+bibliography: biblio.bib
* Content
  Example
* Bibliography
  [cite/n:@ref1; @ref2; @ref3; ...;@refN] 
#+print_bibliography:
```

Comment: Is there no shortcut in the second case? Something like `[cite: @*]` would be convenient (and there is precedent with LatTeX's `\nocite{*}`) - maybe an RFE on the mailing list? BTW, what does `cite/n` do?

Comment: `/n` is for nocite. I found the explanation here : https://blog.tecosaur.com/tmio/2021-07-31-citations.html#cite-styles

Comment: If a shortcut exists (like `[cite/n:@*]`) I didn't find it...

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Comment: You could insert LaTeX `nocite{*}`, then export to LaTeX, then pandoc TeX -> HTML.

Comment: @NickD it seems that `[cite/n:@*]` is the proper syntax, thought it's not currently working (confer https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/69064/cite-all-publications-with-some-author-from-bibtex-in-org-mode)