How to make org-cite show all references in a bibtex file?
I am learning the new org-cite feature in orgmode for citation handling. I have a .bib file. What I need to achieve is to show the bibtex file itself (with formatting) as a HTML or docx file. That is, I need to show all references in a bibtex file in an org document with just
#+bibliography: citationdata.bib

and without any actual citation in the org file.
For this, in LaTeX, there is the \nocite{*} option as said in this answer.
How can I do the same (show all references, cited or uncited) while exporting an org file with org-cite in it?
(This is with Emacs 29, Ubuntu 24.04 LTS; the intended output format is HTML and docx using the biblatex or csl exporter)

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/71817/how-to-export-bibliographies-with-org-mode

If you add [cite/n:@*] somewhere in your document then the bibliography will contain all entries available in the used bib file.
